# Is there any discussion in Jewish Literature regarding Dowsing?

Tags: halacha

There is a method of finding underground water called [Dowsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dowsing), or Water Divination. It involves walking through a field with a stick until the stick moves, which indicates there is water underneath the ground at that point.

Regardless of whether [it actually works](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/730/does-dowsing-aka-water-divining-work), I'm curious if any Poskim speak about it. If so, do they discuss whether it is permissible?

On one hand, I can see it being permissible if it is considered a skill, with no supernatural elements to it (similar to a way a chef is more sensitive to, and able to identify, ingredients and spices in food). On the other hand, I can see it being forbidden if it is considered some kind of witchcraft.

---

[Not that it matters to the question, but I live in an area where most of the water is supplied by wells, and dowsing is the method of identifying where to dig for wells]

Comment: Why are you disregarding whether it works? Why do you assume that the question is somehow unrelated to that?

Comment: Why do you think it would be witchcraft? Which prohibition in particular do you think it might be? What is the category of "considered a skill" and where do you see it relevant to the laws of witchcraft?

Comment: I want to see if rabbis discussed it in the past. I don't care whether people think it works or not. -- when I used the word skill, I meant that it is completely natural and not supernatural

Comment: @mevaqesh, I believe there is Machlokes among the Rishonim (Rambam vs. most others) if Witchcraft actually exists or ever did. According to most Rishonim it is not forbidden unless it works.

Comment: @heshy I know that, but don't see how it clarifies the question.

Comment: @menachem I don't understand why you think it might operate according to the laws of nature, but regardless, clarifications should be edited into the question.

Comment: @mevaqesh, it gives opening to a possible nafka mina if Witchcraft as a prohibition is limited to that which works. Just justifying the qualifying component of the question.

Comment: It can be argued that Hosea 4:12 discusses dowsing as an example of prohibited occult activity: "My people: It consults its stick,Its rod directs it! A lecherous impulse has made them go wrong, And they have strayed from submission to their God."

Answer (score 4):

A new book was recently published titled "[Shulchan HaLevi on Alternative Medicine](https://www.judaicapress.com/products/shulchan-halevi-on-alternative-medicine)". It is a posthumous publication on Rabbi Yisroel Belsky's view of various Energy healing methods. In it (page 36), he clearly forbids Dowsing as a form of Avoda Zara. He adds that - "Furthermore, this whole system fits in exacly with what the Rishonim describe as the prohibition of *kosem kesamim*, divination." Also, there is an unusually long footnote which includes a comprehensive compilation of Responsa prohibiting similar methods.

To quote from the sefer, "If a person discovers that he has a problem or medical condition, he should go to a doctor and get a scratch test; that's the best way to find out what you're allergic to."

Comment: Is kosem kesamim avoda zara? Does he say it is the former or the latter?

Comment: What does the last paragraph have to do with the question?

Comment: To get a clear picture i would suggest you read the Sefer (it's in english). He places many methods under a general title of "Avoda Zara", and he points out that it fits into kosem kesamim. (I try to be careful with my wording)

Comment: Given that kosem kesamim is it's own prohibition, I'm not sure why the two are being conflated. I don't have the work, and I suspect many other users don't either. Answers shouldn't require users to consult other works to understand them.

Comment: I get that, but i think my answer is self contained and understandable. I refer you to the work only because i am not answering with my own authority, but rather quoting a psak.

Comment: Also, the OP seems to be asking according to the possibility that it is effective. (Why anyone would ask such a question, is beyond me). If r. Belsky is only answering according to the assumption that this is not effective according to the laws of nature, then I don't think it answers.

Comment: Great, I edited an update to that effect

Comment: Offhand, I am not aware of any rishonim who understand kosem kesamim prognostications to be naturalistic, so I wouldn't think this answers the question. Consider clarifying. notably, this isn't even attempting to predict the future, as in ohez bmaklo, but to find existing water...

Comment: Wait, are you saying energy healing is kosem kesamim, avoda zara, or some other prohibition? Please clarify. Or better, remove it as distracting information.

Comment: Is the conclusion that it applies regardless of efficacy yours, or his?

Comment: ok, sorry about the second paragraph, in the sefer, the author disscusses dowsing as used to identify allergies, but i think it is safe to assume that all dowsing fall under the same problem

Comment: @mbloch thanks! Btw, I was just pinged,  without the @ sign before my name, is that because it is a comment to my q?

Comment: @mbloch, perhaps search for pendulum dowsing

Comment: https://www.holisticshop.co.uk/articles/guide-pendulum-dowsing

Comment: Interesting - but most likely not what the questioner had in mind - since he mentions water and sticks - not pendulums - just make sure R Belsky is addressing the water dowsing being asked about. Kol tuv